# Finding second and third derivative for Taylor series

Tags: derivatives, taylor-expansion

I'm calculating the 3rd degree Taylor polynomial for $y =$ $x^{x^x}$ in $x_0=1$. 
I calculated the first derivative, which is $e^{lnx*x^x}*(\frac{x^x}{x}+lnx*e^{lnx*x}*(1+lnx))$. Finding the first degree derivative in $x_0=1$ is very easy, but calculating the second and third derivative is not.

Is there any way I can simplify it or do I really have to find all the lengthy second and third degree derivatives of $y$?

Thanks

Comment: $x_0=0$???? That isn't even in the domain of the function. Do you perhaps mean $x_0=1$? I would not do this problem by calculating derivatives. Do you have any other techniques to consider?

Comment: @TedShifrin Oh shoot, I made a typo. $x_0=1$.. Sorry, fixed it. And I'm not sure I know about any other ways. Could you help?

Comment: Here's an easier one. Do you know how to give me the T.P. of degree $4$ centered at $x_0=0$ of $e^{x^2}$ without computing derivatives? (I assume you know the T.P. of $e^x$.)

Comment: @TedShifrin Not sure how without calculating derivatives.

Comment: You substitute $x^2$ for $x$ in the T.P. of degree $2$ of $e^x$. Can you figure out (prove?) why this works?

Comment: @TedShifrin So I just substitute and use a known T.P. to calculate my problem?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm suggesting, although your problem is layers deep. They should have assigned something more reasonable for you to get started on learning.

Comment: @AngelaRichardson Really? A one-sided Taylor expansion? What is it for $x^x$?

Comment: My error. There is no expansion around zero for $x^x$. This is the closest there is to an expansion for$x^x$. https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2322647/15624

Comment: @AngelaRichardson Of course, for things like $\frac{\sin x}x$ or $\frac{e^x-1-x}{\sin^2x}$ we can do Taylor series without a problem. But you really do need real analyticity in a (two-sided) *neighborhood* of the point.

Answer (score 1):

To make life a bit easier, what I would do is
$$y=x^{x^x}\implies z=\log(y)=x\log(x^x)$$for which
$$\frac {dz}{dx}=x^x \left(\frac{1}{x}+\log ^2(x)+\log (x)\right)\to 1$$ $$\frac {d^2z}{dx^2}= x^{x-2} (2 x+x \log (x) (x+x \log (x) (\log (x)+2)+3)-1)\to 1$$ For sure, this is tedious but doable.

We should arrive to
$$z=(x-1)+\frac{1}{2} (x-1)^2+\frac{5}{6} (x-1)^3+\frac{1}{12}
   (x-1)^4+O\left((x-1)^5\right)$$
Now

$$y=e^{z}=1+(x-1)+(x-1)^2+\frac{3}{2} (x-1)^3+\frac{4}{3} (x-1)^4+O\left((x-1)^5\right)$$