# Asymptotically expanding $\int x^{\cos(x)} dx$ as $x \rightarrow 0$.

Tags: real-analysis, limits, asymptotics, taylor-expansion

As the title says, I'm trying to expand the first couple of terms in the asymptotic expansion of $\int x^{\cos(x)} dx$ as $x \rightarrow 0$.

To start things along, I tried expanding $x^{\cos(x)}$, rewriting it as $x x^{\cos(x)-1}=x \exp((\cos(x)-1) \log(x))$ and then expanding the exponential part into a Taylor series. So:

$\int x^{\cos(x)} dx=\int\left(\frac{x}{0!}+\frac{x}{1!}\left(-\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}-...\right)\log(x)+\frac{x}{2!}\left(-\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}-...\right)^2\log^2(x)+... \right) dx$ using the fact that the $-1$ and the $1/0!$ cancel out.

Now how do I find the terms, and how do I figure out which order I put them in? I can see first that we get some integration constant, $c$, and then we get $\frac{1}{2} x^2$. What about after that. There are series within the series, so what order to put things in is where things get tricky. I've made a bunch of attempts, but basically it all gets very complicated trying to figure out which things disappear more slowly than other things as $x$ approaches $0$.

Comment: [THIS](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2322635/taylor-expansion-of-xx-at-x-0) might be of interest.

Answer (score 1):

You can re-arrange the expansion of $x^{\cos x}$ into the form
$$
x^{\cos x}  = x - \frac{\log x}{2}x^3  +  \ldots  = \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  Q_n (\log x)x^{2n + 1} ,
$$
where $Q_n$ is a polynomial of degree $n$. Then
$$
\int_0^x t^{\cos t}\, \mathrm{d}t  = \frac{1}{2}x^2  - \frac{4\log x - 1}{32}x^4  +  \ldots  = \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty P_n (\log x)x^{2n + 2} ,
$$
where $P_n$ is a polynomial of degree $n$ that satisfies
$$
P'_n (z) + (2n + 2)P_n (z) = Q_n (z).
$$